# Can't Insert a Date into the Database by Building the SQL Statement with String Concatenation

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
   cmd.CommandText = "insert into EmailSenderMaster(Date,FContent)Values('" & sendobj.FDate & "','" & email.Body & "')"
```

Here Date is not inserting in to the SQL DATABASE.What could be wrong."The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated." error is showing. But every where I declared fdate as date itself not varchar.

**EDIT**

WHEN I TRIED IT INSIDE THE FOR LOOP SECOND TIME WHEN IT GOES THROUGH THE LOOP ,IT IS SHOWING ERROR

```
             For Each obj In List

           CMD.CommandText = "insert into EmailMasteR(From,RecDate,)Values(@from, Recdate)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", obj.From)
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recdate", obj.RecDate)
                        ''''
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
```

Comment: See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to learn why you shouldn't even _try_ to do this.

Comment: See also [xkcd: Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: sendobj.FDate is Date datatype

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was about to flag that as not constructive, but then.. HAHAHAHAH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error happened because `FDate` which is Date type passed to query as string.
Using `SqlParameter` pass value as Date type to the query
SqlParameters will protect against Sql injection too

```vb
cmd.CommandText = "insert into EmailSenderMaster(Date,FContent)Values(@Mydate, @EmailBody)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mydate", sendobj.FDate)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailBody", email.Body) 
'Execute query
```

Or create `SqlParameter` with explicitly specified value as @Tim suggested.
`.AddWithValue` will need to determine `SqlDbType` of given value,
if you know types of your database columns it is better to specify `SqlDbType` too

```vb
Dim paramDate as New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Mydate", 
                                        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
                                        .Value = sendobj.FDate}
Dim paramBody as New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@EmailBody", 
                                        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                        .Value = email.Body}
cmd.Parameters.AddRange({paramDate, paramBody})
```

Or do it in only two lines

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mydate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = sendobj.FDate
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailBody", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email.Body
```

If you executes same command inside loop
then before creating/adding new parameters clear SqlParameterCollection `cmd.Parameters.Clear()`
Or because your query and parameters are same(only values changes) try next approach

```vb
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO EmailMasteR(From,RecDate)Values(@from, @Recdate)"
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, yourSqlConnection)
    Dim paramFrom As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@from", SqlDBType.NVarChar)
    Dim paramDate As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Recdate", SqlDBType.Date)
    For Each obj In List
        paramFrom.Value = obj.From
        paramDate.Value = obj.RecDate
        ''''
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: WHEN I TRIED IT INSIDE THE FOR LOOP SECOND TIME WHEN IT GOES THROUGH THE LOOP ,IT IS SHOWING ERROR.Pls see the above EDIT

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: The variable name '@Efrom' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: that happened when I paste it here.Real error is above

Answer (score 0):

'Presume, your short date-time format is dd/MM/yyyy in your regional settings.

'Now you could insert record(s) in a SQL database in two different ways:

'1) Using simple query
   Dim tempDate as string = "30/12/2014" '30th Dec 2014
   Dim sqlQuery = "Insert into tbl_SampleTable (DateColumn) Values('" & Format(Cdate(tempDate),"dd/MM/yyyy") & "')"

'2) Using stored procedure
   obj.AddCmdParameter("@InsDateColumn", Dtype.DateTime, tempDate, ParaDirection.Input, True)